# Вопрос про конструктор строк

Tags: c++, строки, символы, строковый-литерал

```
string h;
h = 's' + "ss";// справа строка?
cout << endl << h;// выводит странный символ 
 
string h1('s'+"ss");// конструктор есть
```

Вопрос: какой тип в итоге получается если 's'= char, "ss"= const char[3], который при сложении скорее всего( я не уверена) преобразуется в const char*

Comment: *"пишет что нет конструктора"* Неправда, компилируется. `const char[3]` превращается в `const char *`, а `char` - в число (`s` = 115 в ASCII). Получается указатель на 115-ый элемент массива (выход за границы массива).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да, с конструктором я перепутала, а вот про массив немного не поняла, то есть мы вышли за границы массива и попали в какое-то другое место в памяти, а как оно так может преобразоваться в строку, если по этому адресу вдруг лежит какой-то файл?

Comment: Формально, это неопределенное поведение - программа может упасть, может напечать мусор, может еще что-то сделать. Там вряд ли файл - там какие-то данные вашей программы.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а почему  если сделать так string h1("ss" + 1) , то мы передвинемся на 1-й элемент в массиве и это 's' типа const char, и нормально срабатывает конструктор у h1 и выводится просто s, а изначально h1('s') нельзя?

Comment: `"ss" + 1` имеет тип `const char *` (указатель на 1-ый элемент, начиная с 0), не `char`. Попоробуйте `"abcd" + 1` для наглядности. `std::string`, когда ему дают `const char *`, берет все символы до нулевого байта.

Comment: поняла, спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если неохота пользоваться отладчиком etc, делаем так:

```
string h;
h = ' ' + "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
cout << endl << h;
```

И видим, что вывод идет `GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`, т.е. пропущены 32 символа строки. Наверное, то, что ASCII-код пробела — 0x20 (32) — не простое совпадение? :)

Так что у вас просто получается строка *далеко* за пределами выделенной памяти, т.е. UB. На что там наткнется указатель, кто знает...